# Suppose $f:A \rightarrow B$ and $g \subseteq f$, prove that there is a set $A' \subseteq A$ such that $g:A' \rightarrow B$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This does not seem to require a complicated proof, but I do not really know how to deal with existential proofs.

Comment: Put all the details about your question in the question body, not just the title.

Comment: @JensRenders I'm new to the community so I'm still learning the rules; what if I have a really short question that doesn't require elaboration?

Comment: @ZhihanYang: The body of your question *should* be self-contained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $A' := \{a \in A: (a, b) \in g \text{ for some }b \in B\}.$

Now, we verify that $g$ is indeed a function from $A'$ to $B$.

It is clear that given any $a \in A'$, there exists $b \in B$ such that $(a, b) \in g$. (This is by the construction of $A'$.)
Now, we must show that if $(a, b) \in g$ and $(a, b') \in g$, then $b = b'$. This will follow from the fact that $g \subseteq f$ and that $f$ was a function to begin with.

To elaborate: $g \subseteq f$ tells that $(a, b) \in f$ and $(a, b') \in f$. Now, since $f$ is a function, we must have $b = b'$.

Comment: Is there a reason why we can't directly define $A'$ as $\{ a \in A | (a, b) \in g \text{ for exactly one } b \in B \}$

Comment: You *can* do that. However, then you would then have to prove the first property (which had followed from construction in this case). That is, you'd have to show: given any $a \in A'$, there exists $b \in B$ such that $(a, b) \in g$. (This would be true and will once again, follow from the fact that $f$ was a function.)

Comment: I see. So basically, first proving existence and then proving uniqueness is the standard procedure to verify if some relation is a function, right?

Comment: Yes, you could so. In general, if you want to show that "some object" is "something", you would simply verify that the given object satisfies the definition of the something. (In this case, the object was $g$ and "something" was "a function".)